# With SharePoint Online, how can I remove a News item that is a 'link' rather than a 'post'?

Tags: sharepoint

Referring to the instructions at:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-share-news-on-your-sharepoint-sites-495f8f1a-3bef-4045-b33a-55e5abe7aed7

... I did the steps under "Add a news post by using a link', but it now seems impossible to remove
such a post by the steps under "Delete a news post or news link". Did Microsoft forget to invent
a way to remove a News item that is a 'link' rather than a 'post' on SharePoint Online? Can you tell me how?

Comment: Side note: there is a [SharePoint dedicated StackExchange site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

@Bruce M,

Add more post/links(such as 5) to the news webpart then it will appear 'See All' button.

[image]

Click it (or directly visit '/_layouts/15/news.aspx') then go to the management page, there you can delete the link or post.

[image]
[image]

Result:
[image]